# Salesforce Performance testing using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, salesforce, performance-testing

I was trying to get aura.token from on of the url in salesforce but after correlation and passing the correlated value to subsequent request i am getting the below issue

{"event":{"descriptor":"markup://aura:systemError","attributes":{"values":{"message":"[AuraClientInputException from server] Unexpected request input. Expected input format: "Data in a request must be a valid JSON Object and must be in the expected format."."}}

I tried content-type:application/json

due to this some unusal error occur in my script.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't think you can do Salesforce performance testing at all, as far as I'm aware on-premise deployments are not possible and SaaS offering might be a subject to restrictions, see [Performance test FAQs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387059&type=1)

Second: in this form your question cannot be comprehensively answered.

I can only suggest the following:

- Use [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to see the request you're sending and ensure that it's a valid JSON using i.e. [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)
- Use [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) with the aforementioned View Results Tree listener to see whether JMeter Variables holding correlated values:

  1. exist
  2. have anticipated values

If you want our help you're supposed to provide:

1. Working request (i.e. from browser developer tools)
2. Request from JMeter (i.e. from View Results Tree listener)

preferably with all information like URL, [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), payload, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother performnace testing Salesforce unless you have a non-standard agreement that includes a performance SLA.  The standard contract for Salesforce only includes an uptime SLA with no response time committments.  If you do decide to head down the Salesforce path then Salesforce will need to approve all of your test plans, audit your scripts, and dictate where (what instance) and when (time and date) when you execute your tests.  This is spelled out in the customer agreement with Salesforce.

Instead, spend the time tuning your front end customizations in functional testing.   If you are willing and able to ask performance questions involving a single user then you will be able to find and fix 80% of the items that cause poor performance.   You will not, however, be able to get Salesforce to alter items that are within their SaaS domain of ownership and control.

Be efficient in your use of Labor.  Apply it to the areas where you can control and affect change.  Monitor those areas where you cannot.